# Why is it not replacing all NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        'col3': [3,5,78,3,2,4,11]
    },
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [1,12,3,14,5,16,7],
        'col2': ['a', 'b', 'ac', 'd', 'e', 'af', 'g'],
        'col3': [3,5,78,3,21,4,1]
    },
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
)


x = df1.compare(df2)
x = x.where(pd.notnull(x), None)

print(x)
```

After I use this function `x.where(pd.notnull(x), None)` I still get `NaNs` an not all of them are replace woth `None`.

The output I get is as follows:

```
  col1        col2        col3      
  self other  self other  self other
1  2.0  12.0  None  None   NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN     c    ac   NaN   NaN
3  4.0  14.0  None  None   NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN  None  None   2.0  21.0
5  6.0  16.0     f    af   NaN   NaN
6  NaN   NaN  None  None  11.0   1.0
```

Why is this?
Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly well for me.

Comment: Why do you need to replace `NaN` with `None`?

Comment: `x = x.replace(np.nan,None)`?

Comment: Because I want to write to a json afterwards and `None` becomes `Null` and `NaN` stays that way so the json is just wrong.

Comment: For some reason replacing `None` with `[None]` seems to work.

Comment: @Dave4048 Pandas has `.to_json` function that handles `NaN` for you